# Why does my query return inconsistent amount of rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have what seems like a basic query:

```
select 
item
,prevailingmarketcost as cost
,SuggestedRetail as price
,SuggestedRetail-prevailingmarketcost as profit
from sprucedotnet.dbo.inventorystore
where primaryvendorcode = 'MILWAU184'
```

It consistently returns 484 rows. However adding a calculated column to the query causes me to get a varying number of runs with each query. How can this be?

```
select 
item
,prevailingmarketcost as cost
,SuggestedRetail as price
,SuggestedRetail-prevailingmarketcost as profit
,(SuggestedRetail-prevailingmarketcost)/SuggestedRetail as margin 
from sprucedotnet.dbo.inventorystore
where primaryvendorcode = 'MILWAU184'
```

The table has ~85180 records and 151 fields, So I won't add the entire table schema unless it is requested. The fields being calculated are DECIMAL(18,4).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I had a divide by zero error. My database tool was not reporting the error. I was able to reproduce on fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2ff2/1

Update:

The bug is now fixed. 
https://valentina-db.com/bt/view.php?id=8516